# Suggestion request without user entering partial text

Tags: javascript, redquerybuilder

Is it possible to have [RedQueryBuilder](http://redquerybuilder.appspot.com/) make the suggest call when a user clicks on the argument box but doesn't enter any partial text?

For instance, in the screenshot below, the user has not entered any text but just clicked the text box. It would be nice to have suggestions (limited to some user-defined limit, say 10) if the user doesn't know exactly what all NAMEs there are.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid there is currently no built in support for this.

There is an issue, and some code, on github:
https://github.com/salk31/RedQueryBuilder/issues/26

If you comment on the ticket it should help it get into the next release.

Comment: As a matter of fact, it's actually working, I wan't handling the case args.query == null in JS. Seems like the call is made as soon as text box is clicked.

Comment: Very odd. I'll try and reproduce. Which build are you using 0.6.0 or 0.7.0?

Comment: Sorry for the delay... I've looked carefully at the code and it shouldn't be doing that. So I'm puzzled but if it is working for you the all is well!?